# mathematical notation for defining a variable inside a conditional expression

Tags: notation

I have the following conditional expression on $f$ and I want to use a variable which is only used inside the expression. I'm wondering what would be the best typset for defining it there.

Here is the expression and $\beta$ needs to be defined here.

$ f=\begin{cases}
    0,& \text{if } \alpha\geq 1\\
    \beta+4,              & \text{otherwise}, \text{(here is the question, where to put the definition) }, \beta:=\text{some expressions}
\end{cases} $

can I say,

$ f= \begin{cases}
    0,& \text{if } \alpha\geq 1\\
    \beta+4,  & \text{otherwise}, \\ \beta:=\text{some expressions},           
\end{cases} $

Or,

$ f= \begin{cases}
    0,& \text{if } \alpha\geq 1\\
    \beta+4,  & \text{otherwise}, \\ \text{where } \beta:=\text{some expressions},           
\end{cases} $

Or maybe,

$ f= \begin{cases}
    0,& \text{if } \alpha\geq 1\\
    \beta+4,  & \text{otherwise},~ \beta:=\text{some expressions},           
\end{cases} $